# asp:Button Event Fire on click 'shift'

Tags: asp.net

I Have a Code like

TextBox

```
<input id="myinput" type="text" runat="server" />
```

Button

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnsave" Text="SAVE" OnClick="btnsave_Click" OnClientClick="save();" class="button button2" style="display:none;" />
```

i want to generate   **btnsave_Click** Event when click on Shift Button on keyBoard, Is this Possible??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to trigger the Save on shift click everywhere or just inside the TextBox. So here are both.

Entire page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 16) {
            $("#<%= btnsave.ClientID %>").click();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Or just inside a TextBox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body input[type=text]').keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 16) {
            $("#<%= btnsave.ClientID %>").click();
        }
    });
</script>
```